# getting related objects in template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

in app engine, i have a model like this:

```
class Matchday(ndb.Model):
    num = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Match(ndb.Model):
    matchday = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Matchday')
    home = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Team')
    away = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Team')
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

i retrieve all the items of Matchdays and Match like this:

```
matchdays = Matchday.query().order(Matchday.num).fetch()
matches = Match.query().order(Match.date).fetch()
```

and pass them to the template (using jinja2).
on the template, i want to list all the matchdays und list the corresponding matches inside these matchdays with nested lists like so

```
% for matchday in matchdays %}
    {% for match in matchday.matches %}
        {{ <<do somethin with the match here>> }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

this obviously won't work. inside the nested for-loop, how can i retrieve only the matches, that belong to the specific matchday? can that be done with the KeyProperty i implemented, or do i have to change my model?

Comment: take a look at my app https://github.com/presveva/tornei_all_italiana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the KeyProperty is comparable with another keys of same kind

```
matches = Match.query(Match.matchday == matchday.key).fetch()
```

edit:

add this to Matchday model and your code works

```
@property
matches = Match.query(Match.matchday == self.key).fetch()
```

Comment: thanks. only problem is that this won't work inside the templates. i think about using the KeyProperty with repeated=True on the Matchdays Model, to represent a one-to-many-relation as a list of keys

Answer (score 0):

This will perform one query every time your template calls `{% for match in matchday.matches %}`:

```
class Matchday(ndb.Model):
    num = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

    def matches(self):
        return Match.query(Match.matchday == self.key).order(Match.date)
```